# Friend functions of a class template

Tags: c++, friend, function-templates, non-member-functions

I have a class template `Foo<T>`.

I'd like to implement a non-member function `Bar` that takes two `Foo`s and returns a `Foo`.  I want `Bar` to be a non-member because it will be more natural for callers to write `Bar(f1, f2)` than `f1.Bar(f2)`.  I also want `Bar` to be `inline` because the calculation is trivial and frequent.

```
template <typename T>
inline Foo<T> Bar(const Foo<T> &lhs, const Foo<T> &rhs) {
  ...
}
```

The trick is `Bar` needs access to `Foo`'s private data.  I'd prefer not to have accessors to the private data--there's no good reason to expose the private data to users.  So I'd like to make `Bar` a friend of `Foo`.

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
  ...
  private:
    T w, x, y, z;
    friend Foo<T> Bar(const Foo<T> &lhs, const Foo<T> &rhs);
};
```

Here's where I run into trouble.  The compiler complains:

> The inline specifier cannot be used when a friend declaration refers to a specialization of a function template.

Is this rule imposed by the standard or is it specific to MSVC++?

Here's what I've tried:

- Make `Bar` a const public member function, and then to declare a non-member version that simply returns `lhs.Bar(rhs)`.  This seems the least hacky solution.
- Remove the `inline` hint, knowing that the compiler is going to decide about inlining regardless of the hint.  Does this then run afoul of the one-definition rule?  It will still have to be defined in a header file because it's a function template.
- Declare the member function with a dummy template type:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  class Foo {
    ...
    private:
      T w, x, y, z;

      // Note that this declaration doesn't actually use Dummy.  It's just there to
      // satisfy the compiler.     
      template <typename Dummy>
      friend Foo<T> Bar(const Foo<T> &lhs, const Foo<T> &rhs);
  };
  ```

I'm not entirely sure why that works, but it does satisfy the compiler.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the calculation is trivial, I would write:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
  ...
  private:
    T w, x, y, z;
  public:
    friend Foo Bar(const Foo &lhs, const Foo &rhs) {
        ...
    }
};
```

This doesn't fall foul of the ODR - it's an inline function with external linkage (3.2/5 excludes this from the ODR subject to the definitions being identical, 7.1.2/3 says that it's inline).

However, this doesn't define a function template `Bar<T>`, it just defines a set of function overloads for `Bar`. There may be some reason, unstated in the question, that means this won't work for you because you actually need the template.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, and it solves the problem nicely meeting all the constraints.

Answer (score 2):

I like option 1 the best:

```
template <typename T>
inline Foo<T> Bar(const Foo<T> &lhs, const Foo<T> &rhs) {
    return lhs.Bar(rhs);
}

template <typename T>
class Foo {
  ...
    Foo<T> Bar(const Foo<T> &other) const;
  private:
    T w, x, y, z;
};
```

Then the functionality is safely contained within the class, but you provide a wrapper function for convenience.

Comment: +1.  I'm liking this more and more for my specific case.  I'm still curious about the general case.

Answer (score 1):

Bar is a template, so it has to be a template in the friend declaration as well.

You don't necessarily have to use a dummy parameter, but could rather use

```
 template <typename U>
 friend Foo<U> Bar(const Foo<U> &lhs, const Foo<U> &rhs);
```

You cannot use T as the template parameter here, as there is already an outer T in scope.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't seem right that Foo<T> would declare a friend function for Bar<U> where U is a different type than T.  Possibly there's no real harm, but it felt wrong.  That's how I ended up with the dummy parameter.

Comment: It might seem wrong, but currently (C++03) you cannot select your friends for a specific T. Your Dummy parameter can also be any type different from T.